Filter vector by proportion of negative values
I have a vector with ordered negative and positive values:
 x <- c(-35, -30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 5, 22, 77)

I need to filter the values in the vector by a certain proportion of the negative values. Say, while I want to keep all positive values, I only want to retain the last third of the negative values. I do have a solution for that but it looks awfully bulky:
data.frame(x) %>%
  mutate(x_neg = ifelse(x < 0, x, NA),
         id = consecutive_id(x_neg),
         x_neg_length = length(x_neg[!is.na(x_neg)])) %>%
  filter(id > x_neg_length/3*2) %>%
  select(x)
      x
1     -5.0
2     -2.0
3     -1.0
4     -0.5
5     0.0
6     5.0
7     22.0
8     77.0

Is there a more concise/more elegant solution (preferably a dplyr one)?

Where is the -1 coming from?

Ah, thanks for spotting this. Have corrected this in edited version.


Re-write
Updated to corrected data.

Note the difference between floor() and ceiling().
I think base is best here. However, a {dplyr}-solution is given as well. I assume that x (vector) or X (data frame) is ordered (by x).
> # Base with floor()
> X[-seq(floor(sum(x < 0) * 2/3)), ]
      x y
7  -5.0 G
8  -2.0 H
9  -1.0 I
10 -0.5 J
11  0.0 K
12  5.0 L
13 22.0 M
14 77.0 N
> # tail(X, floor(sum(x < 0) * 2/3) + 1)
> 
> # just indexing x 
> x[-seq(floor(sum(x < 0) * 2/3))]
[1] -5.0 -2.0 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  5.0 22.0 77.0
> 
> # Base with ceiling()
> X[-seq(ceiling(sum(x < 0) * 2/3)), ]
      x y
8  -2.0 H
9  -1.0 I
10 -0.5 J
11  0.0 K
12  5.0 L
13 22.0 M
14 77.0 N
> # tail(X, ceiling(sum(x < 0) * 2/3) + 1)
> 
> # just indexing x 
> x[-seq(ceiling(sum(x < 0) * 2/3))]
[1] -2.0 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  5.0 22.0 77.0
> 
> # dplyr::slice_tail + floor
> dplyr::slice_tail(X, n = floor(sum(x < 0) * 2/3) + 1) # |> pull(x)
     x y
1 -2.0 H
2 -1.0 I
3 -0.5 J
4  0.0 K
5  5.0 L
6 22.0 M
7 77.0 N
> 
> # dplyr::slice_tail + ceiling
> dplyr::slice_tail(X, n = ceiling(sum(x < 0) * 2/3) + 1) # |> pull(x)
     x y
1 -5.0 G
2 -2.0 H
3 -1.0 I
4 -0.5 J
5  0.0 K
6  5.0 L
7 22.0 M
8 77.0 N


Note
x = c(-35, -30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 5, 22, 77)
X = data.frame(x, y = rep(LETTERS[seq_along(x)])) 


Probably you can try
data.frame(x) %>%
    mutate(grp = consecutive_id(x < 0)) %>%
    reframe(x = tail(x, round(n() / 3^(last(x)<0))), .by = grp) %>%
    pull(x)

which gives
 [1]  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   1   2   3   4 -10  -5  -2   0   5  22  77


A non-dplyr solution, which follows a similar methodology as above, is using rle + by, say
unlist(
    by(
        x,
        with(rle(x < 0), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)),
        \(v) tail(v, round(length(v) / 3^(v[1] < 0)))
    ),
    use.names = FALSE
)

which also gives
[1]  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   1   2   3   4 -10  -5  -2   0   5  22  77

Data
x <- c(-20:-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, -35, -30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -2, 0, 5, 22, 77)


Interestingly this gives me an error: Error in 'reframe()': Caused by error in 'nth()': ! 'order_by' must have size 20, not size 1.

@AndreWildberg that's interestingly weird .. I cannot understand why that error happened ...

The second argument of dplyr::last is order_by and it should be An optional vector the same size as ‘x’ used to determine the order. It seems you're using data.table::last

@AndreWildberg aha, you are really a genius detective! Nice catch! You are right that the second last is from data.table, but I was not aware of it. Thank you so much!

An approach using proportions.
Edit with new data.
library(dplyr)

data.frame(x) %>%
  filter(cumsum(proportions(as.matrix(x < 0), 2)) > 2/3)
     x
1 -5.0
2 -2.0
3 -1.0
4 -0.5
5  0.0
6  5.0
7 22.0
8 77.0


Assuming x is ordered, get last 3rd of negative values, and keep all other values:
x <- c(-35, -30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 5, 22, 77)

ix <- which(x < 0)
x[ c(tail(ix, ceiling(length(ix)/3)), which(x >= 0)) ]
#[1] -5.0 -2.0 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  5.0 22.0 77.0

x[ c(tail(ix, floor(length(ix)/3)), which(x >= 0)) ]
# [1] -2.0 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  5.0 22.0 77.0


This can be done with the tail function, the trick is knowing how many leading entries to remove.

compute the number of negative values sum(x < 0), yielding 10
divide by 3, and drop the decimal floor(sum(x < 0) / 3), yielding 3
remove 3 entries by using a negative number for the n = argument in the tail function.

Drop the first 3 negative entries
tail(x, n = -floor(sum(x < 0) / 3))

 [1] -20.0 -15.0 -10.0  -5.0  -2.0  -1.0  -0.5   0.0   5.0  22.0  77.0

If you would rather round up and drop the 4 negative values instead of 3 use ceiling instead of floor

To get the right result the n option of the tail function would need to be +10 or -4 because they want the positive numbers too.  So tail(x, n = floor(sum(x < 0) * 2/3) + sum(x >= 0)) would work also
